# How to fix ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - MERN Stack Heroku Deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

I deployed to heroku and my app displays but not my API. My console states GET http://localhost:5000/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I am not sure what the issue is because I am able to run the application locally without any issues and I am not seeing any errors in my Heroku logs.

[image]

SERVER

```js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import path from 'path'

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js'

const app = express()

dotenv.config()

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "32mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "32mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes)
app.use('/user', userRoutes)

// Serve static assests in production

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')));
}


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/instaverse", ({
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
}))
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Package.JSON

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "env": "^0.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.12",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

Client Package JSON

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }

}
```

Actions Folder Posts - This is where the Network Err is at my getPosts()

```js
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE} from '../constants/actionTypes.js'
import * as api from '../api'

// Action Creators

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts()

        console.log(dispatch);
        console.log(data);

        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: data })

        console.log("GETTING POSTS");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

}


export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        console.log(post);
        const { data } = await api.createPost(post)

        console.log(data);

        dispatch({ type: CREATE, payload: data })

        console.log("CREATED POSTS");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const updatePost = (id, post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.updatePost(id, post)

        dispatch({ type: UPDATE, payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

export const deletePost = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await api.deletePost(id)

        dispatch({type: DELETE, payload: id})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

export const likePost = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.likePost(id)

        dispatch({ type: UPDATE, payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

API FILE

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'})

API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('profile')) {
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).token}`
    }

    return req;
})

export const fetchPosts = () => API.get('/posts')
export const createPost = (newPost) =>API.post('/posts', newPost) 
export const updatePost = (id, updatedPost) =>API.patch(`/posts/${id}`,updatedPost)
export const deletePost = (id) =>API.delete(`/posts/${id}`)
export const likePost = (id) =>API.patch(`/posts/${id}/likePost`)


export const signIn = (formData) => API.post('/user/signin', formData)
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signup', formData)
```

Comment: What is in the api file?

Comment: I added my API file to the post. Im not really seeing anything unless my const API is incorrect.

Comment: Your API is hard-coded to make requests to localhost. This works when the client and server are running on the same computer. When the client and server are on different computers, the client's computer makes a request to itself, which fails because the server isn't running on the same computer.

Is it possible to check an environment variable to decide what the `baseURL` should be? For example, in production use your Heroku app's URL, otherwise use localhost.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts That was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, don't you have to change the baseUrl of axios when deployong the application? Or does it stay the same? I'm not sure myself, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your environment variables in your application settings in Heroku?
If not than it might explain why you are getting this error, since your `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is not configured.

Heroku is working a little different with environment variables, you can check [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) how it works.

Comment: I do have a config vars set up with my Key = MPNGODB_URI and my Value being my MONGODB Atlas cluster. My .env file is set up like PORT = 5000 and MONGODB_URI =  'mongodb+srv://Name:<password>@cluster0.1d7qs.mongodb.net/myfirstdatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

Comment: Did you read the Heroku article on config vars? you should have your environment vars set app in your app setting and not a `.env` file.
Also, why are you using localhost? when you deploy an app to Heroku you get a domain name to use.

Comment: Yes, so I dont know if I am missing something but I went to my app settings and set my key to MONGODB_URI and the value to mongodb+srv://Name:<password>@cluster0.1d7qs.mongodb.net/myfirstdatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority. It gives me the same error. I am not setting it in the CLI but on the Dashboard. . . I have a .env file so I can work on the app locally and then deploy. It is just what I learned in bootcamp but again I am connected fine locally and able to access the api. My IP address is set to 0.00.0/0, Idk if that is an issue.

Comment: Did you change the Name and <password> in the URI to your username and password? I know it's silly but sometimes it's those small things.
Also, I just remembered that you need to add your IP to your cluster IP address list. Check your settings there and update.
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/add-ip-address-to-list/